# Django scheduled tasks

Tags: django, celery, scheduled-tasks

i want to display the current exchnage rate of USD/Bitcoin price-pair on my website.
Therefor i set celery and a small periodic_task.
Im currently not really able to understand  how i call this periodic_task task or display the json data it returns.

this is how my celeter setup look like:

__init_.py

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
    from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
app = Celery('myproject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
import requests

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://127.0.0.1')



@app.task
def test():
    return "Test Successful"


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/15')), name="get_btc_exchange_rate", ignore_result=True)
def get_exchange_rate():
    api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=1"
    try:
        exchange_rate = requests.get(api_url).json()
        logger.info("BTC Exchange rate updated.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        exchange_rate = dict()
    return exchange_rate
```

I'm currently stating celery with this script:
https://gist.github.com/psych0der/44a8994495abee1b4e832420c1c2974d

So my question is how can i trigger that periodic_task and display the return of the json data/field "price_usd"? in a template

Thanks in advance

Comment: To answer the second part of you question: `exchange_rate[0]['price_usd']` will get the price_usd. But, are you sure celery is the correct tool for your task? Maybe look into JS and ajax if you're not saving the rate and just updating the display.

Comment: Hello,

i need celery for many things in the end but first i have to understand it ;)
Merci for your feedback.

Comment: When you say display it, do you mean return it to the client browser? or you just need it logged somewhere?

Comment: It would be awesome if i could catch the price_usd into a database field as somekind of cache thats gets refreshed every x minutes

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start a celerybeat instance. It will schedule and send off events that you can set on an interval.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: Thanks for this hint. im now able to get the data :D
but how do i display it?
I have no experience in JSON formatting with python/django

Comment: If you found this helpful Venom you should select it as the answer and ask your new question as a new question.